# HAProxy ACL to check if connected to OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, haproxy

Suppose I have an HAProxy instance directing traffic to a webserver.

I want to block traffic to a target directory, unless the user is connected to OpenVPN.

OpenVPN is set to the "Routing" configuration, not the "Bridged" configuration, so the source IP is the same, whether the user is on VPN or not.

What approach can I take to setup this ACL?

Thank you

---

What I have so far:

```
frontend https
    bind *:443
    mode http

    acl restricted_path path_beg /restricted
    acl is_vpn_user [[I don't know what to do here]]
    http-request deny if restricted_path !is_vpn_user

    default backend normal_traffic
```

Comment: Problem is HAProxy need http headers to inspect the traffic and openvpn does not have a header. The only way I can see it is to move openvpn to port 80 and use something like `use_backend regulay if HTTP  and  use_vpn if !HTTP` - then block the dirs in the webserver configs.

Comment: For clarify, I am handling HTTP(S) traffic in both scenarios. If the user is on the VPN, allow access to a restricted directory. If they are not on the VPN, black traffic instead.

Comment: Updated question with example snippet

Comment: You can detect the source IP of vpn connections which are typically in a specific subnet. For example, `acl is_vpn_user src 20.30.40.50 8.9.9.0/27`.

Comment: Because OpenVPN is in routed mode, it's not using the WLAN. Unfortunately, source IPs appear to be the same whether the host is on the VPN or not